# Unicode support (including emoji) in web application with accent insensitive collation

Tags: mysql, perl, unicode

I have a legacy web application using Perl, CGI, and MySQL 5.5.62. In fields completed by customers, I need to support the umlaut and emoji characters that they often use in their input.

In an attempt to learn, I set up the following stand-alone test. (It's deliberately very simple and lacking basic security checks on input.)

Dump of database `widget`:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `experiment`;
CREATE TABLE `experiment` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `content` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

LOCK TABLES `experiment` WRITE;
INSERT INTO `experiment` VALUES (1,'Record','Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country. ðŸ˜€\r\nThe quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dÃ¶g.');
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Perl code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -T

use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;
use CGI '-utf8';

my $dbh = DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:widget','test','test', { mysql_enable_utf8 => 0,}) or die "Can't connect to the database: $DBI::errstr";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM `experiment`') or die "Couldn't prepare statement: " . $dbh->errstr;
$sth->execute or die "Can't execute SQL statement: $DBI::errstr";
my $hashref = $sth->fetchrow_hashref or die "Can't fetchrow_hashref: $DBI::errstr\n";
$sth->finish;
my $search = '';
for my $i (qw(fox dog)) {
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `experiment` WHERE `content` LIKE '%$i%'") or die "Couldn't prepare statement: " . $dbh->errstr;
    my $count = $sth->execute or die "Can't execute SQL statement: $DBI::errstr";
    $search .= "<h6>String: [$i] found [$count]</h6>";
}
$sth->finish;

my $action = CGI::param('action') || '';
if ($action eq 'save') {
    my $new = CGI::param('value') || '';
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE `experiment` SET `content` = '$new' WHERE `id` = 1") or die "Couldn't prepare statement: " . $dbh->errstr;
    $sth->execute or die "Can't execute SQL statement: $DBI::errstr";
    $sth->finish;
    print "Location: http://simulated-domain-name.com/cgi-bin/test.cgi\n\n";
    exit;
}
$dbh->disconnect;
print <<EOF;
Content-type: text/html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous"> <!-- not part of the experiment, just make it look nice -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container my-3">
            <h5>Content = $hashref->{content}</h5>
$search
            <form method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="font-weight-bold" for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Content</label>
                    <textarea name="value" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3">$hashref->{content}</textarea>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
EOF
exit;
```

As far as I can tell, the `'-utf8'` on the line with `use CGI` has no effect.

When using `mysql_enable_utf8 = 0` the program works beautifully *but* accent insensitive search fails. Umlauts and emoji are properly displayed in the browser.

Output:

> Content = Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dög.
>   String: [fox] found [1]
>   String: [dog] found [0E0]

When using `mysql_enable_utf8 = 1' the HTML output looks scrambled.

Output:

> Content = Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country. ðŸ˜€ The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dÃ¶g.
>   String: [fox] found [1]
>   String: [dog] found [0E0]

I feel like I'm close, but missing something important.

Comment: Looking at the docs I think you want mysql_enable_utf8mb4 not mysql_enable_utf8? And you should tell Perl that standard output should be using utf-8 via `use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';` or the like if you're writing out Unicode text.

Comment: The encoding of the emoji in question is 4 byte long, so definitely need `mysql_enable_utf8mb4`. Is that the only issue?

Comment: @Shawn Your code didn't help, but `binmode(STDOUT, ":encoding(UTF-8)");` did. With `mysql_enable_utf8 => 1` the operation of my test was improved: umlauts are saved and displayed correctly, and my test search for "dog" works. However, emoji are now saved as four question marks. The `mysql_enable_utf8mb4` setting doesn't seem to be available in my environment. It has absolutely no effect.

Comment: @ikegami By testing, I have determined that my environment doesn't support `mysql_enable_utf8mb4`. Not sure how to get that going.

Comment: Re "*Your code didn't help*", uh, `use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';` does `binmode(STDOUT, ":encoding(UTF-8)");`

Comment: @ikegami For me, `use open` didn't work, but `binmode` did. I don't know why. My Perl is v5.16.3.

Comment: Version doesn't matter. The `:std` part tells it to binmode STD*

Comment: what DBD::mysql version?  utf8 support varies dramatically by version.  DBD::MariaDB (a fork, which also supports both mysql and mariadb servers) has better out-of-the-box utf8 support, at the cost of more backwards incompatibility

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Emoji --> `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`.

Accent insensitive --> any `COLLATION utf8mb4_..._ci`.

Since you are on the relatively antique 5.5, you may run into the "767 problem".  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes

If you have Question marks or Mojibake (such as `dÃ¶g` for `dög`), see [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

My notes on Perl:

```
use utf8;
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:mysql:".$dsn, $user, $password, {
   PrintError => 0,
   RaiseError => 1,
   mysql_enable_utf8 => 1,  # Switch to UTF-8 for communication and decode.
});
# or {mysql_enable_utf8mb4 => 1} if using utf8mb4
```

(I don't have any notes on `use CGI`.)

Comment: By testing, I have determined that my stack doesn't support `mysql_enable_utf8mb4`. Yum on CentOS 7 says perl-DBI-1.627-4.el7.x86_64 and perl-DBD-MySQL-4.023-6.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version. Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: I was just looking at that. I think my problem is the yum repository is 4.023 and I need DBD::mysql 4.050 for support of `mysql_enable_utf8mb4`. I guess I would uninstall the repository and manually install the new version.

Comment: That's pretty old.  I have a file with `our $VERSION = '4.033';` with a copyright of 2013.

Comment: @TimothyB. - You can probably install from cpan, bypassing `yum`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that worked for me on CentOS 7:

- Install mysql-devel (via yum) because mysql_config was not on my system
- Upgrade Perl DBD::mysql from 4.023 (via yum) to 4.050 (via CPAN)
- Use `mysql_enable_utf8mb4` option in `DBI->connect`
- Add `binmode(STDOUT, ":encoding(UTF-8)");` to top of Perl script

Output is now as desired:

> Content = Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dög.
>   String: [fox] found [1]
>   String: [dog] found [1]